# How to update value inside shared preferences in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

actually when saving data inside shared preferences.. I am using this code

```
add() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('data', "ok");
}
```

but, is there a way to update the value of `data` for example I want to change `ok` into `fine`
because when I try to re-save my data using that code... and call it using `prefs.getString('data');` it always shows the old data not the update one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just reassign it again

```
prefs.setString('data', "fine");
```

Comment: but whenever I call it ```prefs.getString('data');``` it always shows the old data (```ok```) not ```fine```

Comment: try in terminal `flutter clean` before running app or `prefs.reload();`

Comment: Where should I put prefs.reload() ?

Comment: `prefs.reload();` then `prefs.getString('data');`

Answer (score 0):

//shared-preferences

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString('profileImg', data1['imagePath']);
        prefs.setString('un', data1['username']);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it